# How to convert date string back to unix time with GREL (OpenRefine)

Tags: date, time, openrefine, grel

I'm working with a large CSV file with millions of rows. I'm using OpenRefine to manipulate this large data set.

I have a column with date strings in this format "2017-08-17 04:36:00". And I would like to convert them to Unix time in integer format like 1502944560.

I see many Q&A on converting Unix time to Date String but not the other way around. Is this possible in OpenRefine?

Answer (score 4):

`value.toDate().datePart("time")`

(see the bottom of [this documentation](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/GREL-Date-Functions) for other conversion strings)

Comment: I actually tried it but didn't convert `toDate()` first. Thanks!

Comment: There is probably an issue with your string. Could you copy paste the exact content of one of your cells?

Comment: Sorry, I miscommunicated. It's working! Thanks for saving me bunch of time.

Comment: It's a common mistake. The `datePart()` method only works on an object of type 'date', not on a string that looks like a date. ;)

Comment: Added to our official FAQ on OpenRefine Wiki https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/Recipes#how-to-convert-date-string-back-to-unix-time